# How to list only my outgoing changes in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to get a list of the files I've modified and committed before I push.

I can generally do this OK with hg outgoing.

But if I pull in some additional changes, after I've committed mine, then those new changes are also listed, and they are even listed under my name.  I did do a commit of the merge, but nothing really merged, I just pulled in an unrelated changeset.  If I'm pulling in a lot of changes from other users, my changes get lost in all of these changes.

Is there a way to list just my changes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use log with revset's function and some template keywords in order to get such filelist

`hg help revsets` suggests usage of outgoing():

```
"outgoing([path])"
  Changesets not found in the specified destination repository, or the
  default push location.
```

`--template "{files}\n"` give you space-separated list of files in each changeset in range and newline-separation of sets from different changesets. `--template "{files % '{file}\n'}"` do the trivk "file per line"

You can pipe output of log to sort in order to get sorted, without duplicates, list of files

Final draft `hg log -r 'outgoing()' --template "{files % '{file}\n'}" | sort -u`

Comment: +1 but don't you need the revset `outgoing() and not merge()` to exclude files only affected by outgoing merge changesets?

Comment: Very nice.  I noticed I can use the --no-merges option with log as well.  So this gets me exactly what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
hg outgoing --no-merge
```

to filter out the merge changesets (`-M` is the short version see `hg help outgoing`).

If you are pushing to the same repo from which you pulled the changesets authored by others, you should only see the changesets you created.